# Component doesn't react on any change of data in the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a state which gets new data into it, and I want to show this data what I add on a same page where i add it. When I load a page, state is not empty, for example there are 10 items, then I add 11 item, 12 item..., but I still see same 10 rendered items on my page. Problem is that the component which reads data from the state, loads data only when page was opened, but doesn't load new data when it was added.

Here is the beginning of the code for adding a new friend:

```
    let addNewFriend = () => {
        let name = newFriend.current.value;
        debugger;
        if (name === '') {
            alert('You can\'t submit empty field')
        } else {
            props.onAddFriend(name);
            console.log({contactsItem})
        }
    }
```

messagesReducer

```
const messagesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MESSAGE:
            let newMessage = {
                name: 'Sasha', text: state.newMessageText
            }
            state.chatData.push(newMessage);
            state.newMessageText = '';
            return state;
        case UPDATE_NEW_MESSAGE_TEXT:
            state.newMessageText = action.newText;
            return state;
        case ADD_FRIEND:
            let friend = state.newFriendName;
            debugger;
            state.contactsData.push( {name:friend, road:`/${friend}`} );
            debugger;
            action.newFriendName = '';
            return state;
            debugger;
        case UPDATE_NEW_FRIEND_NAME:
            state.newFriendName = action.newName;
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const addNewFriendActionCreator = () => {
    return {
        type: ADD_FRIEND,
    }
}

export const onNameChangeActionCreator = (name) => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_NEW_FRIEND_NAME,
        newName: name
    }
}


export const addMessageActionCreator = () => {
    return {
        type: ADD_MESSAGE,
    }
}

export const onMessageChangeActionCreator = (text) => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_NEW_MESSAGE_TEXT,
        newText: text
    }
}
```

State and dispatch

```
let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state: state,
        newFriendName: state.newFriendName
    }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onAddFriend: (name) => {
            dispatch(addNewFriendActionCreator(name));
        },
        onNameChange: (name) => {
            dispatch(onNameChangeActionCreator(name));
        },
    }
}

const MessagesContactsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessagesContacts);
```

Thats how i render data

```
let contactsItem = props.state.messagePage.contactsData.map((Contact) => {
    return <ContactItem name={Contact.name} road={Contact.road} />
});
```

I debugged the whole process of adding a new item, and I know that everything is fine there, in other words it adds new item to state, thus I found that problem is in the component which is responsible for rendering data.

Comment: You are mutating the `state.contactsData` array by pushing directly into it. You should create and return a new array reference with the new value appended. Also, FWIW you are using extremely outdated Redux patterns. It is highly suggested you update and start using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), you'll end up writing about half as much code, e.g. cut out all the boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update your reducer like this.

```
const messagesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        chatData: [
          ...state.chatData,
          { name: 'Sasha', text: state.newMessageText }
        ],
        newMessageText: ''
      };
    case ADD_FRIEND:
      return {
        ...state,
        contactsData: [
          ...state.contactsData,
          { name: state.newFriendName, road: `/${state.newFriendName}` }
        ],
        newFriendName: ''
      };
    case UPDATE_NEW_FRIEND_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        newFriendName: action.newName
      };
    case UPDATE_NEW_MESSAGE_TEXT:
      return {
        ...state,
        newMessageText: action.newText
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```